# Drawing in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics

This is my first time drawing, so it must be something very stupid, but my drawRect: method doesn't work...
Here is my code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.width / 2, self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height / 2);self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height / 2)
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    CGFloat radius = (self.bounds.size.width > self.bounds.size.height) ? self.bounds.size.width - 30 : self.bounds.size.height - 30;
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextAddArc(ctx, center.x, center.y, radius, 0, 2 * M_PI, YES);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}
```

Comment: Does it not work at all or does it draw not as you'd expect? Also, why oh why the `#define CENTER`?

Comment: That was just to try `#define`, I can leave it away. And it doesn't draw at all, I added a UIView in IB and set the class to my class `FaceView` (yes, Stanford cs193p)

Comment: I ALWAYS forget: @mattjgalloway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The radius of an arc is measured from its center. You're using almost the entire view's width/height, so that the arc will be drawn outside of the visible area. Use a smaller radius and you'll see your arc.

Btw, if all you want is to draw a circle (an arc with an angle of 2π is the same), `CGContextAddEllipseInRect` is easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

you are drawing the circle just outside the view. `CGContextAddArc`takes radius as parameter. In your case, you are giving the method diameter.
Quick fix:

```
radius/=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is working. It's actually drawing, but you can't see the circle, as the radius variable probably get's a big value that make the circle to be drawn outside the bounds of the view.
Just replace manually radius value with a value, say 20, and you'll see that's working fine.

Regards